# How to define base class that handles database connection?

Tags: c#, database, class-design

I have a console application with a base class as following:

```
public abstract class PaymentSystemBase : IPayable
{
    private SqlConnection _connection;

    protected PaymentSystemBase()
    {
        CreateDatabaseConnection();
    }

    protected void CreateDatabaseConnection()
    {
        if(_connection == null)
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connString"];
            var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            _connection = connection;
            connection.Open();
        }
    }

    public SqlConnection Connection
    {
        get { return _connection;  }
    }

    public abstract void ProcessPayment();
}
```

And have a few classes that derive from PaymentSystemBase:

```
public class PS1 : PaymentSystemBase
{
    public override void ProcessPayment()
    {
         // Work with database using Connection from PaymentSystemBase
    }
}

public class PS2 : PaymentSystemBase
{
    public override void ProcessPayment()
    {
         // Work with database using Connection from PaymentSystemBase
    }
}
```

In main program:

```
var lstPayments = new List<IPayable>
{
    new PS1(),
    new PS2()
};

var processPayments = new ProcessPayments(lstPayments);
processPayments.Process();
```

Where:

```
public class ProcessPayments
{
    private List<IPayable> _paymentSystems;

    public ProcessPayments(List<IPayable> paymentSystem)
    {
        _paymentSystems = paymentSystem;
    }

    public void Process()
    {
        foreach (var paymentSystem in _paymentSystems)
        {
            paymentSystem.ProcessPayment();
        }
    }
}
```

My question is how to use the same connection from PaymentSystemBase class and close it after processing? As I can see the connection was created again every time when PS1 and PS2 were created.

Comment: use a try catch with finally block where you are implementing actual database operations, then define a connection close method in parent class and call it in finally in the child classes, so that you are sure when DB operations are done, the connection is closed, as per current code, it will be better to call close method after PS1 and PS2 have finished inside the Main function

Comment: I could *guess* that this is c#, but I shouldn't have to. Please edit your question and add a suitable language tag. But if this is .NET, then I'd say, please stop trying to do this. You shouldn't *try* to share connection objects around. You should create and open a connection immediately before you need to use it and close/dispose of it immediately afterwards. The connection pool takes care of limiting the number of actual physical connections used.

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever: Yes, this is C# code. I've added that information in original post. You mean I should open and close database connection every time when I work with PS1, PS2 and so on objects?

Comment: I said put it in the *tags* (Which I've now done) You'll notice that now the code samples have syntax highlighting, as a bonus of adding the correct language tag.

Comment: And yes, the only thing you should be sharing around is the connection *string*.

Comment: Ok. I've got the requirement to refactor old code where everything was in Main method. I mean the connection was opened once, PS1 and PS2 processing were in static methods (not in classes) that used the connection and the connection was closed after all. If I refactor it in this way where I open and close connection every time, will it be slower?

Comment: What's wrong with the code of `PS1.ProcessPayment` and `PS2.ProcessPayment` residing in a simple static method and passing it the connection as parameter? If they don't need any kind of state, then there are probably no reasons to complicate things and putting them into classes.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't *try* to share the connection object. The connection objects themselves are actually quite lightweight, being an abstraction built on top of the actual physical connections, that the ADO.NET connection pool takes care of creating.

So you base class should be something like:

```
public abstract class PaymentSystemBase : IPayable
{
    private static string _connectionString =
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connString"].ConnectionString

    public static string ConnectionString
    {
        get { return _connection;  }
    }

    public abstract void ProcessPayment();
}
```

And then your derived classes should be:

```
public class PS1 : PaymentSystemBase
{
    public override void ProcessPayment()
    {
        using(var conn = new SqlConnection(PaymentSystemBase.ConnectionString))
        {
           using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("...",conn)
           {
               //Prepare command
               conn.Open();
               cmd.ExecuteXXX();
               //Process results, etc
           }
        }
    }
}
```

You'll notice that I've also switched where the connection string is loaded from via the `ConfigurationManager` class from `AppSettings` to `ConnectionStrings`, which is a dedicated part of the configuration system for storing connection strings. This wasn't actually required but it is more conventional.